# Issue of addition of blank row in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I have fetched data from db table, bound it to gridview and then export data from gridview to excel. It works fine.

But when I added a row at the top of gridview in databound event by using below code:

```
protected void gvReports_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (gvReports.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);

        int count = gvReports.HeaderRow.Cells.Count;
        TableHeaderCell cell = new TableHeaderCell();
        cell.BorderWidth = 0;
        cell.Text = "Commodity " + ddlCommMFArrival.SelectedItem.Text;
        cell.ColumnSpan = count - 2;
        row.Controls.Add(cell);
        row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#f5fafd");
        gvReports.HeaderRow.Parent.Controls.AddAt(0, row);
    }
}
```

Code to export Gridview to Excel:

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < gvReports.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < gvReports.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
        {
            if (gvReports.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text == "NA")
            {
                gvReports.Rows[i].Cells[j].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
            }
        }
    }
    gvReports.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Visible = false;
    gvReports.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Visible = false;
    string filename = string.Empty;
    int ddlselect = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCommMFArrival.SelectedValue);
    if (ddlselect == 1)
    {
        filename = "MarketFee" + DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/", "").Replace(":", "").Replace(" ", "") + "";
    }
    else if (ddlselect == 2)
    {
        filename = "Commodity Arrival" + DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/", "").Replace(":", "").Replace(" ", "") + "";
    }

    //Export gridview data into MS Excel
    blExportToExcel blExport = new blExportToExcel();
    //Export gridview data into MS Excel
    blExport.ExportGridViewToExcel(gvReports, this, filename);
}

    public void ExportGridViewToExcel(GridView grv, System.Web.UI.Page pg, string fileName)
    {
        grv.AllowPaging = false;

        pg.Response.Clear();
        pg.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".xls");
        pg.Response.Charset = "";
        pg.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";

        System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
        grv.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
        pg.Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
        pg.Response.End();

        grv.AllowPaging = true;
    }
```

Then it adds a blank row at position 0 as well as in excel (export data from gridview to excel) and truncates the last row from gridview. Anyone knows what is the issue?

Comment: How and when do you export data to Excel?

Comment: @Eugene Podskal, I have edited my question. Please check.

Comment: did you debug the code ???

Comment: markup needed for the grid!

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar, Yes I have debugged the code, after adding the row to gridview in databound event, a blank row will be added at position 0 in gridview after header row.

Comment: I do not know what the problem is (probably, GridView is not suited for dynamic row additions on DataBound), but what if you add such dummy item to the original data before databinding. You can do it either on SQL side(with UNION if you can change database access routines) or on the web-server side (adding to the datatable(ADO) or to the typed collection(if you use some ORM).

Comment: @NehaGupta any luck with the answer I provided?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your `HeaderRow` addition logic out of `DataBound` and into `RowCreated`. Add this to the `GridView` declaration:

```
OnRowCreated="gvReports_RowCreated"
```

And then this is the `RowCreated` (note the `DataControlRowState.Insert`):

```
protected void gvReports_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);

        int count = e.Row.Cells.Count;
        TableHeaderCell cell = new TableHeaderCell();
        cell.BorderWidth = 0;
        cell.Text = "blah";
        cell.ColumnSpan = count - 2;
        row.Controls.Add(cell);
        row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#f5fafd");
        gvReports.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, row);
    }
}
```